# How can I use the new_type! macro to set a more generic type for a sodiumoxide PublicKey and SecretKey?

Tags: rust, libsodium

I am trying to set a more generic type for a sodiumoxide `PublicKey` and `SecretKey`.

This changes depending if we use `box_` or `sign`:

```
type PubCryptoSecretKey = sodiumoxide::crypto::box_::curve25519xsalsa20poly1305::SecretKey;
```

I would like to set a `PublicKey` type or struct which is compatible with sodiumoxide key's type, something like `struct PubKey(pub [u8; ?])` .

The source of `SecretKey` (or any key) is:

```
new_type! {
    /// `SecretKey` for asymmetric authenticated encryption
    ///
    /// When a `SecretKey` goes out of scope its contents
    /// will be zeroed out
    secret SecretKey(SECRETKEYBYTES);
}
```

where `SECRETKEYBYTES` is of type `usize`

I can not find any information about this `new_type!` macro. What is going on here and how can I go further?

Answer (score 0):

This is [how the macro defines the structure](https://github.com/sodiumoxide/sodiumoxide/blob/2f266b4fc6707a022154215eeb098b6de1d5cd78/src/newtype_macros.rs#L210), but I don't see any good way to easily define generic types for both of them.

A possible solution is to define a new trait in your crate and then implement it for both `PublicKey` and `SecretKey`. The trait should provide you enough functionality to interact with each structure.